# Android Kotlin - Material Bottom Navigation Disable Shift Mode and Selete Menu

Tags: android, kotlin, bottomnavigationview, android-bottomnav

1. I want to Disable Shift Mode with kotlin, I used material BottomNavigationView

   ```
    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    app:itemIconSize="@dimen/iconSize"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/btm_nav_menu"
    app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
    />
   ```
2. I want click account icon and start activity login when click back button homeFragment will be selected not account icon selected

   ```
   bottom_navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
        when(it.itemId) {
            R.id.homeFragment -> showNav(HomeFragment())
            R.id.accountFragment -> { bottom_navigation.menu.findItem(R.id.homeFragment).setCheckable(true)
                startActivity(Intent(this, MainActivity2::class.java)) }
        }
        true
   }


   fun showNav(fragment: Fragment){ 
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().apply {
              replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
              commit()
        }
   }
   ```

Comment: Can you explain better *"disable animate when click icon"*?

Comment: Disable Shift Mode

Comment: `app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"` shoud be enough

Comment: Nope, Also text and icon bigger when click it, I don't want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer 2. Use false, Bottom Navigation will not select the icon

```
bottom_navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
        when(it.itemId) {
            R.id.homeFragment -> {
                showNav(HomeFragment())
                true
            }
            R.id.accountFragment -> {
                startActivity(Intent(this, MainActivity2::class.java))
                false
            } else -> true
        }
    }
```